# How can I print to console from an xcconfig file?

Tags: xcode, xcconfig

I'm trying to debug some internal paths within `xcconfig` files, and I'd love to be able to echo/print/put the paths to see exactly where they're pointing.

Googling "What language is xcconfig?" doesn't give much besides that it's a text file (aren't they all?)

It's looks bash-ish, but `echo` doesn't work, neither does `put` or `print` or `println`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see all environment and custom variables in any 'Run script' under 'Build Phases'.

1. YourConfig.xcconfig:

```
MY_VALUE = 11.0
```

2. Then add 'Run Script' with 'Show environment variables in build log':

[image]

3. Build and look at your logs under 'Report Navigator':

[image]

4. Expand the log to see all variables:

[image]

Comment: Addendum: if you've got multiple targets, make sure to add the run script to the target you're debugging. The env variables can change depending on wiring differences between targets.